# Spring JPA entity inside entity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two tables:
1- USER

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(of= {"id"})
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   //setters getters const ..
}
```

2- REQUEST

```
@Entity
@Table(name="request")
@IdClass(RequestId.class)
public class Request {
   @Id
   private String year;
   @Id
   private String type;
   private Integer idApplicant
   User applicant;
   //setters getters const ..
}
```

the RequestId class is as follow

```
    public class RetardedInsId implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String year,type;
        //setters getter consts ...
    }
```

the repository :

```
pu

blic interface RequestRepo extends CrudRepository<Request, RequestId> {
    }
now, if I call repo.findAll() here:
@Autowired 
RequestRepo repo;
void function()
{
    repo.findAll();
    }
```

I need to be able to have .getApplicant() with id=idApplicant for every found entity .
How?

Comment: 1. You need to model the one-to-one relationship between Request and User. Check this guide for how-to: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one 2. Extend JpaRepository instead of CrudRepository. Then you will get the method findByApplicantId out-of-the-box.